# error with select using Scope_Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to understand what is wrong with this select.
I want to get the last user_Id which was been added.

Here is the error message:
The parameterized query '(@Id_user int)SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id_user' expects the parameter '@Id_user', which was not supplied.

Here is the SQL statement:

```
        if (count >= 1)   /* <===  verification from the insert SQL  */
        {
            string selectStatement = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id_user";
            SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, sqlConnection);
            selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id_user", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Id_user");
            int newID = (int)selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();

            int User_ID = Convert.ToInt32(selectCommand.Parameters["@Id_user"].Value);
            Session["Id_user"] = User_ID;

            buserIdAuthenticated = true;                   
            Session["userIdAuthenticated"] = buserIdAuthenticated;
            Response.Redirect("../pages/Welcome.aspx");
        }
    }

    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
    }

    finally
    {
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: `@Id_User` isn't a parameter, its a return value in the result set.

Answer (score 4):

you haven't defined an @parameter in your sql statement so you don;t need to add the parameter at all - just get the result of ExecuteScalar - you should be able to cast it to an int - although I cast it specifically in the sql statement too -

```
select cast(Scope_identity() as int) ....
```

so you'd end up with somthing like

```
        string selectStatement = "SELECT cast(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS int)";
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, sqlConnection);
        object newIDobj = (int)selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        if(newIDobj!=null)
            Session["Id_user"] = (int)newIDobj;
```

Even better you could create a stored procedure and have the insert done there, where it can then return scope identity.

Edited to include example with insert.  (just typed in here - so likely some typos)

```
int newID = -1;
string commandString = "insert (code, desc, numbervalue) values (@code,    @desc,@numbervalue); select cast(scope_identity() as int);"
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString))
{
    try
    {
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", )
          // etc
          int newid=(int)(cmd.ExecuteScalar()??-1);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         // something went wrong
    }
}

if(newID!=-1)
{
    // do something;
}
```

Comment: This is how we do it.

Comment: @mp3ferret  I got this error at the int newID   error   An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in App_Web_dg5r34gp.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: did you check that the return wasn't null?

Comment: @n8wrl I got this error at the int newID error An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in App_Web_dg5r34gp.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Specified cast is not valid     I did exactly what is mentionned I just changed the Session["Id_user"] = newId;

Comment: @mp3ferret  I didn't check if the return was null because the count is greater than 1 and it means I have 1 row inserted.

Comment: check edit above - to test for null.  When ever I've done this using in code sql I've appended the select scope identity statement to the end of the insert (close the insert command with a ';')  and call executescalar() on that - the scope_identity only has value within the scope of the current command - and your insert, presumably, has already returned.

Comment: @mp3ferret Yes the object is null.. dawn it !!! I understand you do it in one shot (insert + select)  can you show me how do you ensure the insert was done properly if you are just check the Scope_IDENTITY() at the end ?

Comment: if the insert fails you'll either get an exception (most likely), or you'll get null back as the scope identity from executescalar.  no need to check for row count

Comment: @mp3ferret basically I just put the SELECT cast(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS int) at the end of my Insert statement    the question is  how to you get the ID_user if you are using the object for the return ?  object newIDobj = (int)selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: Frankly it is better to use the OUTPUT statment in your insert to get the value(S) inserted. Please look in BOL to find the syntax.